# How to show data from pipe in template?

Tags: angular

I have an array:

```
let arr = [{id: 1, name: "G"...}, {id: 2, name: "H"...}, {id: 3, name: "O"...}];
```

Also there is a template HTML where I need to apply pipe `getTopUser`:

```
<ng-container getTopUser as user>
<div class="top_user">
   <div class="name">{{user.name}}</div>
   <div class="age">{{user.age}}</div>
</div>

<div class="top_user_additional">
    <div class="remark">{{user.remark}}</div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

So I need to apply pipe to block, how to do that properly?

Pipe is:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'applicanttypename',
})
export class TopUserPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(user: User[]): string {
         return user[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the getTopUser pipe as well? And please give an example of what the end result should be

Comment: Sure, I have added

Comment: You should filter user based on some property! on what basis user can be top user?

Comment: No matter, issue is to show it in template?

Comment: I have a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rnsop7. 
I haven't used the pipe yet cause I still don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining it with an `ngIf` directive, you can assign a local variable to use inside the container:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="users | getTopUser; let user">
<div class="top_user">
   <div class="name">{{user.name}}</div>
   <div class="age">{{user.age}}</div>
</div>

<div class="top_user_additional">
    <div class="remark">{{user.remark}}</div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

`users` is the array with users defined in your component. Also note that the name of your pipe is currently `applicanttypename` and not `getTopUser`. And make sure your pipe will handle the case when the input array is undefined or empty.

As @yash mentioned you can also use `users | getTopUser as user`.

Comment: `users | getTopUser; let user` it can be `users | getTopUser as user`?